# Joomla1.5→3.9: Old Artisteer template breaks at a certain variable

Tags: joomla

I'm migrating a site from joomla 1.5 to 3.9. This is also my first time ever touching Joomla, so I'm on bare grounds.
So far, I've managed to install joomla with a fresh install, and template is almost there. We're planning on moving the data manually, since the database is filled with weird stuff from past hacks. Customer wants the template to be as it is, so no new visual things has to be changed.

Whenever I want to view an article, the whole thing crashes.
I have pasted the entire code from `/html/com_content/article/default.php` onto https://pastebin.com/Lr6padqf.

The site breaks at `$canEdit` on `line 5`.

I've searched far and wide, and can't find any solid solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the future, when you have Joomla-specific questions, I recommend that you post them at Joomla Stack Exchange to reach an audience with Joomla-specific expertise.  (This way, even when you discover your own workaround and post it as an answer, other more experienced volunteers can chime in and tell you if you are "doing it properly" or setting yourself up for future headaches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did changes here and there, and only solved things "partially".
Solution was to delete the `com_content` folder, which is inside the `html` folder of the template.

This solution is apparently found everywhere if one googles right. :V